# How to trigger a SharePoint workflow on clicking a link item in the list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-workflow

I have a sharepoint list and user will click 'start now' link in that list, then, I have to start a workflow. How this can be achieved. Please advice!

Thanking you.

Comment: Is this a workflow that you have set up using SharePoint Designer (custom workflow)?

Comment: Kit, No this is a custom workflow not SPD..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this post: [Send email with javascript – with the help of a workflow in a dedicated “send email-list”](http://sharepointjavascript.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/send-email-with-javascript-with-the-help-of-a-workflow-in-a-dedicated-send-email-list/)

Comment: Hi Muhimbi,

Thanks for the answer. But I don't have sp designer workflow. I have a custom workflow which is developed in vs2008. So how can I use the above information to call my custom workflow

Comment: Same way - the javascript puts items in a list and your workflow is triggered when new items are put in the list.